# Best Practices For Django Web App + REST API Architecture as one project

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I am working on my Django project which is going to be a Web App and REST Api for the mobile app.

I am using Django Rest Framework to build the API for the mobile app and it is going pretty good. I like it. For this part, I have a separate app within my Django project. Let's call it 'api'.

What I also want to do, is a web app. Let's call it 'webapp' in my Django project. So basically, web version of the mobile app, with a few different functionalities (e.g. different user/account management) for a slightly different part of the audience. Obviously, the majority of the models that I need, as well as logic are already there in the 'api' app. Also, I want to use Angularjs for the front end of the web app.

My question is what is the best path to take here? Should I create a separate app for my web app and copy the majority of views.py logic, which again will reference models and serializers from the 'api' app in the project? Or should I adjust my existing 'api' app to handle requests from both mobile phones and web app? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow [link](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial#learning-django-and-angularjs). I also follow that link when started angularjs,  django and django-reset-framework.

Comment: Thanks man! I actually finished this tutorial a while back as well. It does cover a lot of useful stuff, but it specifically focused on Angular + DRF. My main question is what's the right way to combine Angular + DRF app AND have it ready to be used as an API for the mobile app. For instance, the tutorial sets up a nice "Account Manager" to manage Account model which overwrites django User model. It actually would work fine for my web app, but for the mobile API, the Account manager won't work., But, majority of other models are good to go.

Comment: You should need to add token based authentication. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Comment: Stack Overflow answers should not just be a link without context.

Comment: @chabislav I started work on an Angular + REST APIs project what me and my team following it like we created a distributed env we create two sprat app `client` for Angular app and `server` for our REST APIs. After that, we integrate APIs withing angular and mobiles. Each app is decoupled from each other.